# Repeat request until condition is met and return intermediate values

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to write a (generic) function `run<ID, ENTITY>(…): Observable<ENTITY>` which takes the following arguments:

- A function `init: () => Observable<ID>` which is an initializing request to start a backend process.
- A function `status: (id: ID) => Observable<ENTITY>` which takes the generated ID and queries the status for it in the backend.
- A function `repeat: (status: ENTITY) => boolean` which determines whether the `status` request must be repeated.
- Two integer values `initialDelay` and `repeatDelay`.

So `run` should execute `init`, then wait for `initialDelay` seconds. From now on it should run `status` every `repeatDelay` seconds until `repeat()` returns `false`.

However, there are two important things that need to work:

- `repeatDelay` should only be counted starting when `status` has emitted its value as to avoid race conditions if `status` takes longer than `repeatDelay`
- The intermediate values emitted by the calls to `status` must also be emitted to the caller.

---

The following (not very pretty) version does everything except for the last thing I mentioned: it doesn't wait for the network response before retrying `status`.

```
run<ID, ENTITY>(…): Observable<ENTITY> {
    let finished = false;
    return init().mergeMap(id => {
        return Observable.timer(initialDelay, repeatDelay)
            .switchMap(() => {
                if (finished) return Observable.of(null);
                return status(id);
            })
            .takeWhile(response => {
                if (repeat(response)) return true;
                if (finished) return false;

                finished = true;
                return true;
            });
    });
}
```

My second version is this, which again works for all but one detail: the intermediate values of the `status` calls aren't emitted, but I do need them in the caller to show the progress:

```
run<ID, ENTITY>(…): Observable<ENTITY> {
    const loop = id => {
        return status(id).switchMap(response => {
            return repeat(response)
                ? Observable.timer(repeatDelay).switchMap(() => loop(id))
                : Observable.of(response);
        });
    };

    return init()
        .mergeMap(id => Observable.timer(initialDelay).switchMap(() => loop(id)));
}
```

Admittedly, the latter one also is a bit of a kludge. I'm sure rxjs can solve this problem in a much neater way (and, more importantly, solve it at all), but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: The loop become recursive in second example

Comment: Your second version can do everything you need by starting your retry stream with your response like `Observable.timer(repeatDelay).switchMap(() => loop(id)).startWith(response)`. In general, you can't really get away from the recursion, because you may need to retry indefinitely and flatmap each attempt into the previous, and most retry operators only supply a void signal. The closest you can get is [`retryWhen`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html) if you're willing to work with errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Observable supports recursion natively with [`expand`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html), also shown in @IngoBürk's answer. This lets us write the recursion even more concisely:

```
function run<ENTITY>(/* ... */): Observable<ENTITY> {
  return init().delay(initialDelay).flatMap(id =>
    status(id).expand(s => 
      repeat(s) ? Observable.of(null).delay(repeatDelay).flatMap(_ => status(id)) : Observable.empty()
    )
  )
}
```

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7y8jvp59/)

---

If recursion is acceptable, then you can do things more concisely still:

```
function run(/* ... */): Observable<ENTITY> {
  function recurse(id: number): Observable<ENTITY> {
    const status$ = status(id).share();
    const tail$ = status$.delay(repeatDelay)
                         .flatMap(status => repeat(status) ? recurse(id, repeatDelay) : Observable.empty());
    return status$.merge(tail$);
  }
  return init().delay(initialDelay).flatMap(id => recurse(id));
}
```

Try [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLd5smrq/1/).

Comment: I think this doesn't do the right thing: it first waits, then calls init and status right after one another. What I need is call init, wait initialDelay, call status and from now on always wait repeatDelay + status.

Comment: @IngoBürk Ah, neither of my answers were correct then. I've updated both.

Comment: Is it possible to limit `status()` call to a certain max number of invocations? Then emit error value?

Answer (score 2):

The [`repeatWhen`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/repeatwhen.md) operator looks tempting on its own, but it only provides a void stream of `onComplete` notifications, so you can't decide to repeat based on the values without some outside help. Here, `BehaviorSubject` is probably your best bet:

```js
function run(/* ... */): Observable<ENTITY> {
  const last_value$ = new BehaviorSubject();
  const delayed$ = init()
    .delay(initialDelay)
    .flatMap(id => 
      status(id).repeatWhen(completions => 
         completions.delay(repeatDelay)
                    .takeWhile(_ => repeat(last_value$.getValue()))
      )
    ).share();
  delayed$.subscribe(last_value$);
  return delayed$;
}
```

Here, `repeatWhen` only resubscribes to the cold source of requests if the last value from the last request is a status that signifies repeating.

[Try the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jkptrtfh/1/)

**Caveat**: there might be a race condition risk when `repeatDelay` is small between the notifier (the function passed to `repeatWhen`) executing and the BehaviorSubject receiving the corresponding status. For a given observer, we're guaranteed that all `onNext` notifications happen before an `onCompleted` notification, but here our `BehaviorSubject` and `repeatWhen` are separated. From a glance at [the source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/8fa95ac884181fb6cbff8ce7c1d669ffb190f5e4/src/modular/observable/repeatwhen.js#L80), it looks like the `onNext` notifications are passed right through `repeatWhen`. I *suspect* the same is true with `concat`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks! This looks good, but I've actually also come up with a solution that just chains things. I'd appreciate if you looked at it to see if you think there's something wrong with it!

Answer (score 0):

So I've come up with this which appears to work. It uses `expand` to create an infinite sequence of retries and `takeWhile` to determine how long to take from it.

The `takeWhile` hack could be removed by writing a custom operator `takeUntil` taking a predicate function. This currently doesn't exist, see [rxjs#2420](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2420).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2mhcvnog/1/

```
run<ID, ENTITY>(...): Observable<ENTITY> {
    /* This little hack is needed to also emit the final item in the takeWhile() loop. */
    let finished = false;

    const delayStatus = (id, delay) => {
        return Observable.of(null)
            .delay(delay)
            .switchMap(() => status(id))
            .map(status => [id, status]);
    };

    return init()
        .mergeMap(id => delayStatus(id, initialDelay))
        .expand(([id]) => {
            if (finished) {
                return Observable.of([id, null]);
            }

            return delayStatus(id, repeatDelay);
        })
        .takeWhile(([_, status]) => {
            if (repeat(status)) {
                return true;
            }

            if (finished) {
                return false;
            }

            finished = true;
            return true;
        })
        .map(([_, status]) => status);
}
```

Comment: I think `expand` could do the trick all on its own here [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/7y8jvp59/).

Comment: @concat Yeah, that looks to be way better still. Do you want to post it as an answer? That's the one I'll go with, thus the one I'd like to mark accepted.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, much appreciated!